# Grade wrapper task failed with kotlin dsl compilation issues

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-wrapper

Grade wrapper task failed with kotlin dsl compilation issues

I have a project which needs gradle 8.x.x. so i have ran the wrapper task to generate gradlew and gradle-wrapper.properties file. but it was failing with compilation issues. I have got the " Unresolved reference: name" error while running wrapper task. the name method is not available in lower versions.